# Protect SVG from client access

Tags: javascript, protection, svg

I want to make a presentation that consists from some number of slides.
The actual content of the slides is going to consist of vector elements in SVG format.
The transition between slides should be managed with JavaScript.

The question is, whether it is possible to implement this in such way that user can not save the presentation either using simple Save As... or digging into browser's cache?

Also I am thinking about using Raphael (which is JavaScript library) instead of pure SVG. But as far as I know, it's impossible to protect JavaScript from client access since it's meant to run on client side.

So is there any way to get full or some protection from client saving the slides?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot send data to the client and expect them not to be able to save it.

In your case, it sounds like the SVG images are good enough that you don't want to give them away.  Could you render them to a raster format (like png) and include the lower quality png files in your presentation instead?

Comment: No, I don't think that is a good idea. Is there, for example, a way to integrate the svg elements in the web-page in a way that it's not visible in the html code?

Comment: There is no way to put items in the page that cannot be discovered through the html code.